# Loop array that has records from two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When I try to loop through an array that has records from two tables it gives an error when it can't find the attribute from the other record.

The array has two different types of elements. One starts like: `#<Question id: 1,`, the other starts with `#<Answer id: 1,`. How do you get the value of one without it looking for it in the other?

Error:

```
undefined method `option' for #<Question:0x007fcc2c6610e8>
```

How would you bypass or loop through this array to show the attribute value when wanted?

The controller:

```
@pdf = []
@test = Test.find(params[:id])
@test_questions = @test.questions
answers = Answer.all
@all_answers = answers.group_by(&:question_id)
@test_questions.each do |q|
  @pdf << q
  @pdf += @all_answers[q.id]
end
```

The html where I am trying to only show the content attribute value first, then all the option attribute values

```
<tbody> 
<% @pdf.each do |test| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= test.id %></td>
    <% if test.content %>
    <td><%= test.content %></td>
    <% end %>
    <% if test.option %>
    <td><%= test.option %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
```

This is what the array looks like:

```
[#<Question id: 1, content: "How did the chicken cross the road?", question_type: "MC", category: "ip_voice", product_id: 8, active: true, created_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14", updated_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14", user_id: 1>, #<Answer id: 1, option: "It walked", question_id: 1, correct: false, created_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14", updated_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14">, #<Answer id: 2, option: "It was thrown", question_id: 1, correct: true, created_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14", updated_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14">, #<Answer id: 3, option: "It got run over and pushed", question_id: 1, correct: false, created_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14", updated_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14">, #<Question id: 2, content: "Is this working?", question_type: "TF", category: "ip_voice", product_id: 6, active: true, reated_at: "2014-05-13 16:10:53", updated_at: "2014-05-13 16:10:53", user_id: 1>, #<Answer id: 4, option: "False", question_id: 2, correct: true, created_at: "2014-05-13 16:10:53", updated_at: "2014-05-13 16:10:53">, #<Answer id: 5, option: "True", question_id: 2, correct: false, created_at: "2014-05-13 16:10:53", updated_at: "2014-05-13 16:10:53">]
```

**Attempt for SimonW**

```
<% @options = [] %>
<% @test_questions.each do |q| %>
  <tr>
    <td width="40px;">1.</td>
    <td><%= q.content %></td>
    <% @all_answers.each do |a| %>
      <% @options << a.find(q.id) %>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  <% @options.each do |o| %>
  <tr>
    <%= o.option %>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Error:

```
undefined method `option' for #<Enumerator:0x007fcc4181e678>
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: I added it in the question, I do not know how to get the Question attributes seperatly from the Answer attributes. I can call the attributes but how do you get the ones belonging to Question or Answer?

Comment: Why are you keeping both the questions and the options in the same array? Keep it as a separate array and treat each class separately.

Comment: You've gone well wrong here A test has many Questions. A Question has many options and one answer. Do that you get test.questions, question.options and question.answer (if it's been answered)

Comment: @SimonW Because the Answers belong to the question. And there any number of answers. I wanted to be able to loop through them already put together.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, option is an attribute of Answer. A Question has many Answers.

Comment: So loop the answers in the question loop, and treat them as a AR relation.

Comment: Does it have many answers, as in the chicken can cross the road and be throw across it? Or would it be more accurate to say a question has many choices of what the answer could be?

Comment: It will show all the answers. Not just the correct one.

Comment: @SimonW Are you saying to get the answers from the group_by variable? How do you do that?

Comment: That's one option, another is via the relationship between the question and the answer.

Comment: So if Answer.all = a then do a.find_all_by_question_id(q) this gave me undefined method for the find_all...

Comment: They are not answers, they are choices! The answer is the choice(s) the person doing the test, selects. Whether they chose the correct one is of course another question :)  You have a question has many answers and an answer has an option. If a Question had many options (choices), the answer your question becomes simple and obvious.

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson I will quander your logic. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead:

```
@test = Test.find(params[:id])
@test_questions = @test.questions
answers = Answer.all
@all_answers = answers.group_by(&:question_id)
@pdf = @test_questions.map { |q| [q, @all_answers[q.id]] }
```

Then in view:

```
<tbody> 
<% @pdf.each do |question, answers| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= question.id %></td>
    <td><%= question.content %></td>
    <% answers.each do |answer|
      <td><%= answer.option %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
```

### Update - cleaner solution

Controller:

```
@test_questions = @test.questions.includes(:answers)
```

View:

```
<tbody> 
<% @test_questions.each do |question| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= question.id %></td>
    <td><%= question.content %></td>
    <% question.answers.each do |answer|
      <td><%= answer.option %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: undefined method `option' for #<Array:0x007fb5e022aae0> on <td><%= answer.option %></td>

Comment: Great, its working. Let me play with it for a bit. I'll get back :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `respond_to?` to avoid that error and ensure you don't call the `option` method on an object which does not know what to do with it:

```
<% if test.respond_to?(:option) && test.option %>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about iterating through object that response to option method (Duck typing), anyways I agree with SimonW that it's a bad design:

```
  <% @options.select{|i| i.respond_to?(:option)}.each do |o| %>
    <tr>
      <%= o.option %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```